# Error "NotImplemented Error" al momento de solucionar una EDO de segundo orden en Python

Tags: python

¿Alguno sabe a qué se debe el error al momento de soucionar la EDO de la imagen?
También me gustaría saber cómo solucionarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]